# Plot graphs with multiple variables in a For loop

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression

I'm trying to write a loop that loops through all variables in an assigned vector

```
var_name = c("crim","zn","chas","nox","rm","dis","rad","tax",
         "ptratio","black","lstat")
```

and those names will loop through a For loop to create separate graphs.

```
for (i in 1:11){plot(Boston$var_name[i], lm_two$residuals)}
```

However, I kept on getting the same error message:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

Could anyone point out where I did wrong in the For loop?

I'm also hoping to assign x-axis title with each variable that goes through the loop. I tried using

```
xlab = var_name[i]
```

in the loop, but that doesn't extract var_name to the x-axis.

Comment: Not all your data have the save length. You can use `length(Boston$var_name[i])` to check the length of all your variables and the residuals.

Comment: You cannot extract variables from `Boston` like that.  Use `Boston[[var_name[i]]]` instead of `Boston$var_name[i]`.  Your version looks for a variable "var_name" in Boston data.

Comment: @otttoomet thank you! How do I assign the x-axis with each variable name? I tried to used xlab=var[i], but it doesn't extract the var name.

Comment: try `plot(..., xlab = var_name[i])`.  `var_name[i]` is your variable name (as a character string).